# Is there any open source offline navigation routing engine for flutter?

Tags: flutter, maps

is someone aware of a lightweight routing engine for flutter?
It would also be fine if it needs some precalculated things (like .pbf or similar).
It would just need to output a path for origin & destination for cars.
And it should be open source / free (I know HERE supports it for example).

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking for a comprehensive and powerful routing solution, then [flutter_router](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_router) is a good option. If you are looking for a lightweight and easy-to-use routing solution, then [fluro](https://pub.dev/packages/fluro) is a good option. Don't miss [go_router](https://pub.dev/packages/go_router) too.

Comment: I am asking about car / map routing, not in-app page navigation routing :D